# Recursive method print string and counts down by 1 and deletes 1 letter for each recursion

Tags: java, string, recursion, methods, command-line

I'm working on a recursive method that will return and print in my main method a String that will count down by 1 for N. Deleting one letter for each recursion for the string. Until N becomes 1 or until the string has 1 letter. (N being a int on the commandline)

For example if my *command lines aruments* are: 5 valentine

It should output too:

> 5 valentine, 4 alentine, 3 lentine, 2 entine, 1 ntine,

So far I managed to count down the number inputted on the commandline argument. I just don't know how to go about deleting one letter from the string? :o

My code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
      int number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      String word = new String("");
      word = args[1];

      String method = recursive.method1(number);
      System.out.println(method);
   }

   public static String method1(int number){
      if (number < 0){
         return "";
      } 
      else{
         return number + ", " + method1(number - 1);
      }
   }
```

Comment: You will want to pass the string to the recursive method. And lookup `substring` in the documentation for the `String` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read through [`subString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) documentation to understand how to go about taking the portions of a String.

1. Change your method definition to include the `word`
2. Add the `word` to your `return` statement: `return number + " " + word +...`
3. Call substring of the original word from the `1st` index
4. Check for `<=0` rather than `<0`

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
            int number = 5;
              String word = new String("");
              word = "Valentine";
              String method = Recurcive.method1(number, word);
              System.out.println(method);
           }

           public static String method1(int number, String word){
              if (number <= 0){
                 return "";
              } 
              else{
                 return number + " " + word + ", " + method1(number - 1, word.substring(1));
              }
           }
```

Gives,

```
5 Valentine, 4 alentine, 3 lentine, 2 entine, 1 ntine,
```

Comment: Hi PopoFibo, Unfortunately I got an error using your code sample with the Int: 10 and String: ten ? A StringIndexOutOfBOundsException: String index out of range: -1 . Is there a fix to this error?

Comment: @Asiax3 Your String length needs to be equal to number you are passing, for "ten" you use up the entire String in 3 passes and on 4th it subString() tries to look for the 4th index which isn't there

Comment: Awh :(, Do you think you can show me a way for the recursive method to stop when the number becomes 1 or string has only one letter?

Comment: @Asiax3 Change your `if (number <= 0)` to `if (number <= 0 || word.length() == 0)`